# Removing New Lines in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change the html code of my wordpress posts. I need to remove the new line characters inside some section of my HTML code so that I can preserve some bandwidth. I use below code:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = replace( `post_content` ,CONCAT('</script></div></script>',CHAR(10)),CONCAT('</script></div></script>','</div>') )  WHERE ID=979
```

But it does not make any effect on my tables although it should. When I remove CHAR(10) phrase, the code works but it is not the way I want.

Can not CHAR(10) be articulated to a literal in MYSQL? And most importantly how can I achieve to remove the space in above example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use concat

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = replace( `post_content` ,'</script></div></script>\n','</script></div></script></div>')  WHERE ID=979
```

However I doubt you'll save a sensitive quantity of bandwith

Notice that I leaved your tags unchanged, but this way you're replacing each newline with a closing 'div' tag

Comment: \n does not match my sql content. CHAR(10) works when used individually but combined with a literal it does not work.

Comment: isn't it because you use \r\n as line ending ?